# t:Alsa - why it is not working on Linux ARM?

Tags: linux, alsa

I'm trying to run ALSA working on my embedded Linux ARM board. I'm compiling the whole system using buildroot-2017 and after proper compilation I am able to run alsamixer and set its settings. However I cannot play anything - for example "aplay sound.wav" gives input/output error.

On older buildroot-2015.05 the alsa drivers worked fine - I could play audio stream via aplay. In new buildroot - I got I/O error.

The audio controller is TLV320AIC3204 and the embedded device has a speaker.

Anyone knows how the ALSA works - and how to debug od fix such a problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the embedded board have speaker(s) —  or other audio output device?

Comment: Yes it has speaker. I forgot to write that on older buildroot-2015.05 it was working fine. I could run aplay and it played a audio stream.

Comment: Every embedded board is different. If the manufacturer does not support it, there is no sensible way to get it to work.